# Customizing NoHandlerException response with ControllerAdvice

Tags: spring-boot, exception, interceptor, spring-restcontroller

I try to implement a custom error response in a spring boot rest application for 404 errors.
I read many of the solutions presented in stackoverflow, without success.

When I call an invalid entry point I obtain this result:

```
{
    "timestamp": "2022-06-22T10:38:41.114+00:00",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "path": "/ws-facturx/fx2"
}
```

But i'd like to have a response that should look like this:

```
{
    "operationId": "u044eZg2gHwtadqxB5CVv6aeMBjj0w",
    "status": "ERROR",
    "operation": "webserviceName",
    "clientName": "ACME Inc",
    "errorMessage": "Error message from Server",
    "createdAt": "2022-06-22T09:15:04.844+00:00"
}
```

I first tried to use @RestControllerAdvice to intercept the exception when they are thrown.

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = {AppServiceException.class, NoHandlerFoundException.class, ServletServiceException.class })
public ResponseEntity<Object> handleAppServiceException(Exception ex,
                                                        WebRequest req) throws JsonProcessingException {
    FacturxDto request = context.getFacturxDtoContext();
    ErrorMessage errorMessage = errorMessageBuilder(request, ex);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(errorMessage, new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

I also modified my application.properties :

```
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.web.resources.add-mappings=false
```

If i call a non defined entry point I do not reach this method. I tried to use an interceptor.
I firs added a class for adding interceptor to InterceptorRegistry:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    private final ApplicationExchangeContext context;

    public WebMvcConfig(ApplicationExchangeContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ApplicationInterceptor(context)).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

My ApplicationInterception looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    private final ApplicationExchangeContext context;

    @Autowired
    public ApplicationInterceptor(ApplicationExchangeContext context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    //unimplemented methods comes here. Define the following method so that it
    //will handle the request before it is passed to the controller.
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            // si on a un 404
            System.out.println(handler);
            String requestData = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            System.out.println(requestData);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            FacturxDto facturxDto = gson.fromJson(requestData, FacturxDto.class);
            context.setFacturxDtoContext(facturxDto);
            throw new ServletServiceException("404...");
        }
        System.out.println("Done in preHandle");
        return true;
        // return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {
        // HandlerInterceptor.super.afterCompletion(request, response, handler, ex);
        System.out.println(request);
        System.out.println(response);
        if (response.getStatus() == HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND.value()) {
            // si on a un 404
            System.out.println(handler);
            String requestData = request.getReader().lines().collect(Collectors.joining());
            System.out.println(requestData);
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            FacturxDto facturxDto = gson.fromJson(requestData, FacturxDto.class);
            context.setFacturxDtoContext(facturxDto);
            throw new ServletServiceException("404...");
        }
        System.out.println("Done in afterCompletion");
    }
}
```

On the preHandle, i do reach the catch part of the code block but i do not access the RestControllerAdvice method that should handle this exception and build my expected object.

[image]

The exception is thrown. But i do not return it to user. Instead I do have an HTML page.

Comment: Your exception handler doesn't handle a `NoHandlerFoundException` which is what is being thrown, so how should it catch it. Also your interceptor isplain wrong as at the `preHandle` level there is no 404 (or at least not for the case when there is no handler found, no interceptor will be invoked because there is nothing to execute).

Comment: I did also added NoHandlerFoundException to exception handler .... I also implemented ServletService exception that extends ServletException. NoHandlerFoundException is also extending ServletException. Result is the same. I update the content of the question. Even in preHandle i do not have access to RestControllerAdvice method

Comment: Again a `preHandle` or interceptor in totally won't work... There is no handler so no `HandlerInterceptor` (the word **Handler** is quite literally in the name) is going to be invoked for that case.

Comment: The `preHandle` is invoked because it is rendering the `error` page, which is a handler as well. So you are already too late.